# simple pdf download function in zend framework 1.11

Tags: zend-framework

I have pdf file in my server. I just want it downloadable by visitor, I am getting several error. I did make a simple controller and corresponding view file in my view file i added

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/docs/tsap.pdf">download</a>
```

I get error

```
Message: Action "tsapPdf" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()
```

Comment: Is your [rewrite conditions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/project-structure.rewrite.html) set up right?

Answer (score 0):

Add baseurl path for you PDF file

eg.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>/your/pdf/path" target='_blank'>download</a>
```

May be this will work,